# REST API - setting an activity's custom fields

Tags: api, rest

How do I set a custom field value for an Activity via the REST API?

I can create an activity on a contact.  I am looking to set a value for a custom field within that activity as well.

For reference my current POST request looks something like this:

```
<www_path>?entity=activity&action=create&activity_id=0&target_contact_id=0
```

Any insight is appreciated!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the custom field ID of the field in question.  If the ID is 14, you can use:

```
<www_path>?entity=activity&action=create&activity_id=0&target_contact_id=0&custom_14=myvalue
```

In general, if you're asking these sorts of questions, you can answer them best by using the API explorer: **Help menu > Developer > API Explorer**.  You can use it to design your query, and it will build your REST string for you - including looking up custom field IDs.

To get the ID via the GUI, you can go to **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Fields**, then select "View and Edit Custom Fields" for the appropriate group.  If you hover your mouse over the "Edit Field" link, you'll see a URL that ends in "&id=x".  "x" is your field ID.

To get the field ID via the API, do a call to CustomField.get.  Here's a REST call to get the ID of a field called "Mail Designation":

```
/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=CustomField&action=get&json={"sequential":1,"label":"Mail Designation"}&api_key=yourkey&key=sitekey
```

Better still, use CustomField.getvalue to return just the ID:

```
/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=CustomField&action=getvalue&json={"sequential":1,"return":"id","label":"Mail Designation"}&api_key=yourkey&key=sitekey
```

Comment: Jon, thanks for the answer and including that resource.  I believe this is what I need.  Cheers!  -matt

Comment: Jon - a follow up.  Any clue how to get the ID of a custom field via the api or GUI?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mcphilly I edited my answer to include your follow-up question.